# TextView and Button overlap in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, landscape-portrait

I created the view by xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background_repeat">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSelfie"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/help2"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvGidWelcomeScreenTitle"
            style="@style/LargeSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/GidSelfieScreenMessage1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/imgSelfie"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvGidWelcomeScreenMessage"
            style="@style/NormalSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/GidSelfieScreenMessage2"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvGidWelcomeScreenTitle"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGidWelcomeNext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="@string/GidSelfieScreenNextButton"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

It works fine in portrait mode. However, when I changed to landscape, the Button which is set to `parentBottom` will overlap the text. I try few things but seems like it does not work.

Anyone know how I can archive the same view as portrait when I changed it to landscape?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried to use a LinearLayout?

Comment: I think to archive my goal, I need to use RelativeLayout. Because the button needs to be in the bottom of the screen all the time no matter what the above contents are.

Comment: Can you add the buttonview to be below tvgidwelcomemessage and check ?

Comment: It will be right below the TextView. I actually need it to be on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Maybe it could helps, if you add layout_below to your button. Like you set android:layout_below="@id/tvGidWelcomeScreenTitle" for the textView above

Comment: I have tried it already. It will over-write the layout_height and make the button sketch from the position of under the TextView to the bottom of the Layout. This problem sounds really simple but it is actually quite complicate to archive.